# android studioda sdk yüklemeproblemini nasıl çözebilirim

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, visual-studio-code

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

please help me! flutter and android studio problem

Comment: Please rewrite your title to english, nobody understands this.

Comment: Please put title and anything else in english

Answer (score 0):

Open Project in Android Studio. Navigate to `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Android SDK`. Then go to tab `SDK Tools` and select the option `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)`[image: Check Snapshot]

Also run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in cmd